# How do I permanently change a vector in R?

Tags: r, rating

I am trying to simulate a tournament where, in each round, two randomly selected players out of thirteen play, and their [Elo rating](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elo_rating_system) (a measure of their relative skill level) gets updated. Each player has a true underlying skill level `true.rating` and during the tournament, I am storing their ratings after each round I am trying to update `current.ratings` and store each iteration in `ratings.matrix`. This is my code, written in R markdown

```
true.ratings <- seq(from = -2, to = 2, length.out = 13)

current.ratings <- seq(from = -2, to = 2, length.out = 13)
ratings.matrix <- matrix(nrow = 13, ncol = 10000)


i.wins <- function(i, j, p) {
    i.wins <- rbinom(1, 1, p)
    return(i.wins)
}

update <- function (K, i, j) {
  R.i <- true.ratings[i]
  R.j <- true.ratings[j]
  probability_i.wins <- 1/(1 + exp(R.j - R.i))
  probability_j.wins <- 1 - probability_i.wins

  winner.is.i <- as.logical(i.wins(i, j, probability_i.wins))

  if (winner.is.i) {
    replace(current.ratings, i , current.ratings[i] + K*(1-probability_i.wins))
    replace(current.ratings, j,  current.ratings[j] -K*probability_j.wins)
  } 
 if (!winner.is.i) {
    current.ratings[i] <- current.ratings[i] -K*probability_i.wins
    current.ratings[j] <- current.ratings[j] + K*(1-probability_j.wins)
  }

  return(current.ratings)
}


match <- function(K) {
  ij <- sample(1:13, 2, replace = F)
  i <- ij[1]
  j <- ij[2]

  return(update(K, i, j))
}


tournament <- function(K) {

  current.ratings <- match(K)

  for (j in 1:10000) {
    ratings.matrix[, j] <- match(K)

  }
  return(ratings.matrix)
}


ratings.matrix <- tournament(K = 0.01)
```

The ratings method is updated after each round with player `i` and player `j`'s current ratings after playing that match. However, when two different players play in the next round, the ratings of the current player i and j will go back to the original `true.rating` values. I suspect this has to do with me not updating my `current.rating` matrix vector correctly.

This is my first stack overflow post, and I am also new to R. Any other feedback on how I can improve is welcome :)

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with C++.

Comment: I don't know how that tag slipped in there. I've removed it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R tries hard to be a functional language, which means the only way a function affects things in the parent environment is through a return value.  If you want to change a value that belongs in some environment outside of the function, you need to do it the R way.

The usual approaches:

1. Return the `current.ratings` and overwrite it explicitly at the top level.  In other words, your function `tournament()` will need to return a list containing `current.ratings` as well as `ratings.matrix` and then you will need to explicitly overwrite these two variables in the top level environment (after your function call).
2. You will need to pass the environment itself as an argument to the function.  This is R's way of passing by reference.  For example

```
tournament <- function(K, myenv){
  myenv$current.ratings <- match(K)
    for (j in 1:10000) {
    ratings.matrix[, j] <- match(K) 
  }
  return(ratings.matrix)
} 
ratings.matrix <- tournament(K = 0.01, myenv=environment())
```

Notice that you can also  use the much loathed `<<-` superasignment operator in your case, but I do not mention it as an actual solution because I don't want to get hit by any rotten tomatoes.

Comment: Great explanation. I've tried all three, and they all solved the problem. I'll be implementing solution 2. Thank you very much @farnsy